# Brew microsoft-office fail for High Sierra

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, homebrew

I am trying to install Microsoft Office in a Late-2009 iMac version 10.13.6. From the [official store](https://www.office.com) or the Appstore, the downloaded .pkg does not work because it requires minimum version 10.14. I tried to install it with [cask brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/microsoft-office) and it shows the same error.

I appreciate any help to install Microsoft Office to my old PC.

Thanks

Comment: You don’t indicate what error you received

Comment: Nor which version of Office you're trying to install. 2019/365 requires Mojave, 2016 ought to still work for High Sierra but is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry about that. The error says that at least I need to have macOS 10.14. And the Office version I was trying to download was the last available for my OS, which I actually do not know the number.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on 10.13.6 (Catalina) you can't download the newest version of Microsoft Office because you don't meet the minimum requirement of macOS 10.14 (Mojave). Your device does not support macOS Mojave.

As Tetsujin has mentioned in a comment, you can install Microsoft Office 2016, but that is no longer receiving updates from Microsoft.

You can still install the 2016 version with homebrew.

If you're on homebrew v2.7.x you will need to use the following command:

`brew install homebrew/cask-versions/microsoft-office-2016 --cask`

If you're on homebrew v2.6.x or lower, you will need to use the older style command:

`brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/microoft-office-2016`

Comment: I downloaded office-2016 as you said and the auto-update of Microsoft installed the version 16.43. Smooth like butter.